# Dynamically creating Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to dynamically generate a label with a number whenever a button is clicked.
I want labels to be generated with consecutive numbers whenever the button is clicked. (one label at a time)
I am posting the code I wrote below, however, on executing this code only one label is being generated. The onclick event doesn't seem to be firing post that.
please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm17 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

            int x = 400;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //user defined function 
        void GenerateLabel ()
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(l);
            l.Style["top"] = "25px";
            l.Style["Left"] = "60px";
            l.Text = this.x.ToString();
            x = x + 1;

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateLabel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [static variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). If variable should keep its value across all instances of the object then declare it as a static. This will increment *x* on every click

```
static int x = 400;
```